# Which software for online 3D rendering?

Tags: api, command-line, cloud-service, 3d

We are looking for a solution where we can render photorealistic 3D product images on a webserver or in the cloud.

Basically we want to create one 3D model per product and render it with different textures for creating all product images. Since the amount of combinations is quite huge and textures might be created on demand, pre-rendering them offline is no solution.

We tried creating models in Cinema 4D/Maya and rendering them with migenius RealityServer (iRay). Unfortunately we are facing compatibility issues when exporting to .mi files for migenius renderer.

Any other technology stack proposal? Is there any renderer which can be used server-side?

**Requirements:**

- photorealistic
- image output (e.g. JPEG)
- server based
- any mainstream 3D tool for creating assets
- command-based/API based exchange of textures

**Soft requirements:**

- fast render times
- no enterprise pricing

Looking forward to any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a low cost modelling and rendering solution including the possibility of having in-house render farms take a look at [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).

- Price = Free
- Command Line rendering = Yes
- Photorealistic = Very
- Image output = Lots of options including Jpeg
- Server based = Both server and client usage
- Server Farm Usage = Nice description [here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/08/09/setting-up-a-render-farm/).
- Management tools = See [flamenco](http://gooseberry.blender.org/announcing-flamenco-2-0alpha-release/).

For an online rendering service there is a selection listed [here](http://rentrender.com/blender-render-farms/).

Comment: Thanks Steve, I already had a look at Blender but since its not a commercial product, getting the right information is not so straight forward. Which render engine would you recommend?

Comment: @SBehn - I have not done so much with Blender that I have required the use of other render engines, (yet), but I would suggest asking at http://blender.stackexchange.com, http://www.blenderartists.org or one of the sites listed at http://www.blender.org/support/user-community/

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't do command line, you might want to look at the basic / free version of [OneRender](http://www.onerender.com). It can import a few different formats and, photo-realistic is possible with the right combination of textures and native shaders.